# SHOW TABLES LIKE returns a 1064 syntax error in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple call to SHOW TABLES and I'm getting a 1064 syntax error.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE docx_setting");
```

Returns the following error:

```
Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'docx_setting' at line 1

Error No: 1064
SHOW TABLES LIKE docx_setting in
/home/username/dev/web/application/system/database/mysql.php on line 50
```

I've Googled quite a bit and don't see anything wrong with my syntax.  LIKE only supports one pattern so this should be fine.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

--Vince

Comment: That should be a quoted string `LIKE 'docx_setting'`

Comment: Crazy, I tried it like that first and it didn't work, I then tried ticks, and that didn't work ... but ... it's working now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the string must be quoted

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'docx_setting'
```